# Preserve Structure while searching for entries?

Tags: entries, search, sections

I have Structure type section and each of the entry contain at least 10 level 1 entries.

Is there a way to preserve the structure of the entries while filtering/searching entries? What I mean by this is that, I want to search the parent entries only (Ignoring the level 1 *child* entries).

[image]